# Is having multiple service types and service endpoints in a single ServiceHost possible?

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

Working with .NET 3.5 but 4.5 solutions are also welcome.

I have several WSDLs each defining a single unique web service that I need to host as a server. The following code illustrates how I run **a single web service**:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace Playground
{
    class Program
    {
        static BasicHttpBinding GetBinding()
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            binding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            binding.AllowCookies = true;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

            return binding;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
                typeof(ServiceAImplementation),
                new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8081/")
                ))
            {
                host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior));
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(
                    new ServiceDebugBehavior
                    {
                        IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
                    });
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ServiceAInterface), GetBinding(), "ServiceA.soap");

                try
                {
                    host.Open();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException timeoutExp)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Timeout");
                }
                catch (CommunicationException commExp)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Communication problem");
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    host.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking into adding multiple service types and service points to the same host.

Let's say I have the following services:

- `ServiceA` with `ServiceAInterface` and `ServiceAImplementation`, available on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ServiceA.soap`
- `ServiceB` with `ServiceBInterface` and `ServiceBImplementation`, available on `http://127.0.0.1:8081/ServiceB.soap`
- `ServiceC` with `ServiceCInterface` and `ServiceCImplementation`, available on `http://127.0.0.1:8082/ServiceC.soap`

So far I was unable to find a way to make a `ServiceHost` (note the **a**, which means a single!) handle multiple web services. Alone the constructor (`ServiceHost(object, Uri[])` and `ServiceHost(type, Uri[])` clearly point towards a **one host, one service** policy. Of course multiple service end points can be assigned but that doesn't fix the problem I'm facing.

Is there a way to do that or do I have to implement my own custom `ServiceHost` that does it?

**UPDATE:** It seems that my question is somewhat unclear. I know I can create just some other hosts and then basically copy-paste the code from above for each service (I even have created a version where each host runs in a separate thread). I'm looking for a **one host, multiple services** solution. I have already done research on providing multiple service contracts (the web service's interface) through addition of separate service endpoints along with passing a single implementation (the `Service...Implementation`  from the example code above). The problem is that all of the operations have **at least one overlapping operation** meaning same operation signature (return type, name and input parameters) but depending on the web service the return value is different. While yes, imho these services are poorly designed, it's something I have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, read your query wrong before.

If I now understand you correctly, I think this is what you mean:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost hostA = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceAImplementation), new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:6600/"));
            ServiceHost hostB = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceBImplementation), new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:6601/"));

            InitHost<ServiceAInterface>(hostA, "ServiceA.soap");
            InitHost<ServiceBInterface>(hostB, "ServiceB.soap");

            try
            {
                hostA.Open();
                hostB.Open();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timeout");
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Communication problem");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                hostA.Close();
                hostB.Close();
            }
        }

        private static BasicHttpBinding GetBinding()
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            binding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            binding.AllowCookies = true;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

            return binding;
        }

        private static void InitHost<T>(ServiceHost host, string endpointEnd)
        {
            host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior));
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(
                new ServiceDebugBehavior
                {
                    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
                });
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(T), GetBinding(), endpointEnd);

            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (smb == null)
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(
              ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
              MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
              "mex"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of WCFClient (sorry might be blocked by my firewall)]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (not that savvy when it comes to C# and web services) but doesn't the tutorial use 2 hosts? I can clearly see that the XML configuration file has two `<host/>` entries. Also I would like to use code since the configuration I will be using in the future (the example above is just a playground) is a custom one.

Comment: ah, understand you better now, have a look above.

Comment: I already have that (with 3 services). My question is if this can be avoided (multiple hosts with one per web service) and if yes, then how. I have even researched creating a common implementation (what the `ServiceHost` takes) and then simply provide separate service endpoints for the different service contracts (aka interfaces) to it. However in my real scenario this is impossible since the services have some overlapping operations (same names, same arguments and same return type but different return value), which cannot be incorporated in a single implemntation.

Comment: ah, I'm not sure that's possible.  Offhand, best I can think of is interfaces common among the endpoints, which I understand you've tried.   Busy today with other things, but if I think of a pattern that may suit, I'll fire something back.  Meanwhile hope you find an answer, am interested myself if it's possible.